# Rrendering a XML::XPath::NodeSet using an XSLT template with XML::LibXSLT

Tags: xml, perl, xslt, xpath

I need to render a node set found via [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aXPath)

```
my $source = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'xml/animals.xml');
my $nodeset = $source->find('//area[@id="01"]');
```

using an XSLT template  with [`XML::LibXSLT`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXSLT):

```
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();
my $style_doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location=>'xml/animal_template.xsl', no_cdata=>1);
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($style_doc);
```

but I can't simply give the nodeset to the `$stylesheet->transform()`:

```
my $results = $stylesheet->transform($nodeset);
```

because transform is expecting a [`XML::LibXML::Document`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aDocument) object, not  `XML::XPath::NodeSet`.

What should I do? Is there a way to create an `XML::LibXML::Document` from a `XML::XPath::NodeSet`?

Or maybe to give the XSLT template a variable so I don't have to find the nodes with XPath?

Comment: solved using

      $stylesheet->transform($doc, XML::LibXSLT::xpath_to_string(
        param => "string"
        ));


as written in http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXSLT-1.77/LibXSLT.pm

Comment: I don't see how that solves your problem. What are you passing as `$doc`? Previously you had only a `XML::XPath::NodeSet` object to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method to convert an `XML::XPath::NodeSet` object to an `XML::LibXML::Document` object. Furthermore it isn't possible in general as a Nodeset can contain any number of XML elements while an XML document must have exactly one root element.

But XPath is an integral part of XSLT, so there is no reason why you shouldn't rewrite the transform so that it does the selection `//area[@id="01"]` itself, and then supply it the entire document, as parsed by XML::LibXML. This is the method I would choose.

If you have reasons to select the `<area id="01">` elements separately then it would be possible to build a new XML document by converting each element in the Nodeset to a string and bundling them into a dummy `<root>` XML element, but that is far from an ideal solution.

If you have questions about implementing a solution then please ask again.

Comment: "But XPath is an integral part of XSLT, so there is no reason why you shouldn't rewrite the transform so that it does the selection //area[@id="01"] itself, and then supply it the entire document, as parsed by XML::LibXML. This is the method I would choose"

So the best solution is to dynamically rewrite the template every time I need to select and render the elements I have inside a specific Area?

Comment: I didn't realise the XPath expression was variable. Ideally you would pass the information as a parameter to the transform, but it is impossible in standard XSLT to evaluate a parameter as an XPath expression. Depending on the different possibilities of the XPath, you could write `<xsl:template match="*[name()=$node_param][id='01']"` or something similar. To help you further we will have to see the full extent of your transform and the likely contents of your XPath.